# Laravel: Ordenar después de hacer un slice en un objeto

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Actualmente tengo esta línea para hacer un slice en el objeto.

`$projects = Project::slice($offset, $limit)->get()`

El slice me lo hace bien, pero ahora me gustaría hacer un orderby en la misma línea de código.

Algo tipo así:

`$projects = Project::slice($offset, $limit)->orderBy('order','asc')->get();`

Esta línea de código no me da ningún error, pero me devuelve la *data* desordenada.

Como debería de hacerlo para que se ordene?

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El método `slice()` se aplica a colecciones, mientras el método `orderBy()` se aplica al construir el query.

Esta línea, cambiando el orden, debería funcionar:

```
$projects = Project::orderBy('order','asc')->slice($offset, $limit)->get();
```

Comment: Un autentico crack. Gracias @Shaz.

Comment: Un pequeño error! @Shaz el get para que funcione bien, se debe hacer después del slice, gracias igualmente:)

Comment: Modificado, no había probado el código.